# reinterpret_cast a template class to const version

Tags: c++, templates, constants, reinterpret-cast

AFAIK, a template class with template argument `<Type>` is completely distinct from `<const Type>`.

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
  T obj = T{};

  //other code 
};
```

Now I can't pass `Wrapper<int>&` to a function that needs `Wrapper<const int>&`.

```
void someFunc(Wrapper<const int>& wrapper);
//...
Wrapper<int> wrapper;
someFunc(wrapper); //error
```

What can go wrong by `reinterpret_cast`'ing it to its const version?

```
operator Wrapper<const T>&() { return *(reinterpret_cast<Wrapper<const T>*>(this)); }
```

Adding the above line to `Wrapper` makes it work without having to create a new `<const int>` object. `obj` can't be accessed inside the function, so it should not matter if the passed parameter is actually `<const Type>` or `<Type>`.

Provided there is no template specialization, can anything go wrong here (as far as standard goes vs in practice)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of optimizations that can be different between the const and non-const cases, meaning both the memory layout of the class (e.g. since const objects does not need to actually exist) and the usage of the class can be different.

In other words: Using reinterpret_cast for this can result in unexpected behaviour and should not be done.

In my opinion there are several ways where over-eager usage of the `const` keyword can result in more complicated code without any gain, and this is one of them.
I suggest avoiding the `<const Type>` cases instead of trying to handle them.

Without knowing the use case, it seems to me most use cases would be covered by using `const Wrapper<T>` instead of `Wrapper<const T>`.

Comment: Thanks! "both the memory layout of the class and the usage of the class can be different". Can you give any reference for this? Currently I'm using it for an "ID" class that is like a handle to an object. Similarly as with pointers `const ID<T>` and `ID<const T>` mean different things. (`const float*` and `float *const`) And for a resource manager, where if the resource is actual-const then I have to use `const_cast` to cast away constness, unless I use <const T>. if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Newline: It is not required or specified that the non-const and const instantiations should be identical, so I can't give a direct reference to something non-existing ;-) 
The reinterpret_cast is needed because there is no such guarantee. 
If you want to dive into the rabbit-hole of which optimizations can affect only the const case, I suggest looking into "constant folding" or other questions about how const is treated (e.g. [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142475/) )

Comment: I do have the impression that most of your problems are due to over-using the const keyword. The rule-of-thumb is that if you need to cast away constness, it probably shouldn't have been const to begin with. 
Does your ID class need to work differently when referring to a const- or a non-const object? If it doesn't, I strongly suggest always using the non-const version of the template (i.e. `ID<int>`), but instead make the member variable(s) of type `const T`, which should work in both cases.

Comment: If it is `const ID<T>` then I cant modify ID, if its `ID<const T>` then I cant modify the object that it refers to. I want it to be like a pointer, where you can set the constness of the pointer and the pointed object separately. If  the pointer is `int * ptr` then there is no way to point it at a `const int` without const-cast.

Comment: Ok, then you have two different types, `ID<T>` and `ID<const T>`, and should assume them different - i.e. reinterpret_cast will lead to undefined behaviour. 
I do however urge you to consider if all this const-specifying will make any difference to your program, or if it just results in more complex code to handle it.